# Why do we get `possibly null` errors in the if-branch?

Tags: angular

We have enabled [strictNullInputTypes](http://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#template-type-checking) is enabled in [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/tmtron/ng-9-async/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L32).

The component has a simple observable:

```js
export class ExampleComponent {

  obs$ = of({
    prop: 12
  }).pipe(delay(1000));

}
```

In the [component template](https://github.com/tmtron/ng-9-async/blob/master/src/app/example-component.html) we use `*ngIf ; else`, like so

```html
<div *ngIf="obs$ | async as val; else loading">
  val = {{ val.prop  }}
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <div>
    loading..
  </div>
  >
</ng-template>
```

when we build the project we get an error:

```
ERROR in src/app/example-component.html:6:12 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

6   val = {{ val.prop  }}
             ~~~~~~~~~~
```

I did not expect this, since we use an `else` part.

Details:

- I understand that the async pipe will add `null` to the observable type, which is okay. From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors):

  > The async pipe currently assumes that the Observable it subscribes to can be asynchronous, which means that it's possible that there is no value available yet. In that case, it still has to return something—which is null. In other words, the return type of the async pipe includes null, which may result in errors in situations where the Observable is known to emit a non-nullable value synchronously.
- so `obs$ | async as val`can be an `object` or `null`

  - when it is `null`, [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) will render the `loading` template
  - otherwise the `div` will be rendered: so inside of the `div`, `val` will always refer to an object, right?
    **So why do we get the `possibly null` error?**

To **reproduce** the test, download and extract the code from the [simple example on GitHub](https://github.com/tmtron/ng-9-async) and:

- `npm install`
- `npm run build`

**Workaround** is to use this if-expression: `(obs$ | async)! as val; else loading`

Comment: Please, see my answer and if it helps you, vote positive. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** 06.03.2020

The [issue #34572](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34572) is fixed in angular `9.0.5`

**Original**

There is already one open issue there for this issue in [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34572). It's happening

> Because of the semantics of `ngIf`, it is known that the captured
>   context variable is non-nullable, however the template type checker
>   would not consider them as such and still report errors when
>   `strictNullTypes` is enabled.

As you mentioned in the OP Use as any or $any function to disable type checking in template.

> $any() can be used in binding expressions to disable type checking of
>   this expression. This is really similar to as any in TypeScript

```
<div *ngIf="obs$ | async;let val; else loading">
  val = {{ $any(val).prop  }}
</div>
```

Comment:  this very helpful , thanks for sharing with us , is $any a typescript function or angular template function 

Comment: Glad It was helpful. $any is angular template function you can find more info here:https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#built-in-template-functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `OnInit` in your component, and then `strictNullInputTypes` will not fail, because Angular knows that variable `obs$` can never be null, because you initialize in `OnInit`.

A image of your class modified:

[image]

Any doubt ask me.

Comment: I prove with your code, and this don't fail me, i dont want that you lose your time.

Comment: oh - sorry I missed something. Your answer will work - but not for the reasons that you think. It works because you are using an observable of `any` and thus you lose all type checking. In fact, the type of `obs$` should be `Observable<{prop: number}>`. Then you will see the same error again.

Comment: Hmm you're true. And thx for the explanation of the any. Luck for find a good answer.